# Calculating the dot product of vector fields.

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis

Given Two vector fields :

$$X(x,y,z)=(x,-y,-z)$$

$$Y(x,y,z)=(1,-y,x)$$

I want to calculate the dot product of these two vector fields $X.Y$. It's just that its vector fields that is confusing me a little but I assume its similar to calculating for two vectors. Here's what I did.

$X(x,y,z)=(-x,y,z)=xi-yj-zk$

$Y(x,y,z)=i-yj+xk$

$X.Y=(xi-yj-zk).(i-yj+xk)=x+y^2-zx$

This value is a scalar number at each pount (x,y,z).

Is this correct ?

Comment: Yes, it is correct. At least if $\{i,j,k\}$ is an orthonormal basis.

Comment: It is :) so fantastic :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you say vector fields I would write
$$X = x\frac{\partial }{\partial x}-y\frac{\partial }{\partial y}-z\frac{\partial}{\partial z}$$
and similarly for $Y$. The vector fields $\partial/\partial x$, etc. are differential operators acting on functions when you work on a generic manifold. The notation $i,j,k$ (or $e_1,e_2,e_3$) is used instead for three-dimensional vector spaces to denote the standard orthonormal basis. Anyway, if you are working in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $i,j,k$ is the standard orthonormal basis, then your computation is correct.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how to use partial derivatives in the way you explained. specifically i.i=1, but $\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\frac{\partial }{\partial x}=\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial x^2}$. leaving the dot product as $x\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial x^2}+y^2\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial y^2}-zx\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial z^2}$. This doesn't look right to me , am I misunderstanding you ?

Comment: You can think of $\partial/\partial x$ as a function associating to a point $(x,y,z)$ a vector $\partial/\partial x_{|(x,y,z)}$ in the tangent space to your manifold at $(x,y,z)$. If all of this sounds strange, forget it for now. Just remember that when you perform the dot product you are working pointwise, and a vector field at a point is a vector, so the usual rule to compute the dot product holds. Have you already studied manifolds?

Comment: No i don't think we'll start learning about manifolds until near christmas. Also not in this course but in complex analysis. this is probably why I'm finding it difficult to understand the point.

Comment: Do not worry then. Just treat $\partial/\partial x, \partial/\partial y, \partial/\partial z$, as $i,j,k$.